# I can't send recordset and connection to function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a VBA funtion to open a database recordset.

I pass the all the parameters needed to recordset.open, but i get the error:

> missing expression

on this line:

```
RS.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Here is the function:

```
Function sql_request(oConn, RS, part_no) As Variant
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM KC_PROD.DOC_ISSUE WHERE DOC_NO = " & parts_no
    RS.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    dataArray = RS.GetRows
    sql_request = dataArray
End Function
```

and here i call the function:

```
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
data_array = sql_request(oConn, RS, "113946")
```

I have no problem calling

```
RS.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

from the main sub

Comment: Which line has the error? Since adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly and adCmdText are constants, do you need to pass them to your function?  There's no need unless you mean to change their values, in which case you should use different names...

Comment: Your last parameter is names `part_no`, but in the sql-statement you use `parts_no`. This probably causes the error msg. Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Thanks! Option Explicit did the trick. I was not using it.